# Get local datetime using offset SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a date in my SQL Sever 2008 database, for e.g. '2018-07-31 20:41:54.790' as `datetime` and an offset for e.g. '+01:10' as `nvarchar(10)`.

What I want as an output using a query is '2018-07-31 21:51:54.790'.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Other than splitting the offset and using `DATEADD`, I am not aware of any other way.

Comment: I got excited and was about to post an answer using `At Time Zone` to evaluate the offset, but then I realized it was a question for 2008 :(

Comment: @Siyual Yeah I also read about it in my quest for a solution, but alas its SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the edit. Will keep that in mind in near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `CAST` let your column Type to `DATETIME`. then use `CASE WHNE` to check the offset.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col1 VARCHAR(50),
   col2 VARCHAR(10)
);
insert into t values ('2018-07-31 20:41:54.790','+01:10');
insert into t values ('2018-07-31 20:41:54.790','-01:10');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN col2 like '+%' then CAST(col1 AS DATETIME) + CAST(replace(col2,'+','') AS DATETIME)
  WHEN col2 like '-%' then CAST(col1 AS DATETIME) - CAST(replace(col2,'-','') AS DATETIME)
END
FROM T
```

**Result**

**[Results]**:

```
|                         |
|-------------------------|
| 2018-07-31T21:51:54.79Z |
| 2018-07-31T19:31:54.79Z |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2264/1)

Comment: So it seems there is no other direct via function way or something like that, accepting this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the `+` from the offset, cast it to a `TIME`, then cast that time to a `DATETIME` and add it to the original `DATETIME` column.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2018-07-31 20:41:54.790'
DECLARE @Offset NVARCHAR(10) = '+01:10'

SELECT @Date + CAST(CAST(REPLACE(@Offset, '+', '') AS TIME) AS DATETIME)
```

Returns:

`2018-07-31 21:51:54.790`

It's a bit long-winded because you can't directly convert your offset to a `DATETIME`, and you can't directly add a `TIME` to a `DATETIME`, but you can cast a `TIME` to a `DATETIME` and do it that way around.